# Zip list with list of a list in Haskell

Tags: list, dictionary, haskell, zip, tuples

I want to zip `[Int]` with `[[String]]`, so that I get `[[(Int, String)]]`.
An example:

```
[1,2,3] and
[[a,b,c],[d,e,f]] becomes
[[(1,a),(2,b),(3,c)],[(1,d),(2,e),(3,f)]]
```

How could I do this? I have tried a few thing with map, but without success.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to map over the list of strings and zip up the list of ints with each string.

```
Prelude> myzip ints strings = map (zip ints) strings
Prelude> myzip [1,2,3] [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
[[(1,"a"),(2,"b"),(3,"c")],[(1,"d"),(2,"e"),(3,"f")]]
```

Using currying, this can be shortened to

```
myzip ints = map (zip ints)
```

Which can be then shortened to the following using composition:

```
myzip = map . zip
```